# UNIX command to test for fan status

Tags: unix, solaris

anyone know the commands(s) for checking the hardware status of the machine, I'm trying to see if there are issues with the processor fans.

Comment: These command probably differs _a lot_ depending on the system. Can you be more specific about platform/OS?

Comment: Thanks bud, it's Sun 4900 Solaris 9, I just thought there would be a standard command.

Comment: You should add such detail to the question text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Sun hardware, try `prtdiag -v` - it will show the status of all hardware, but presentation is not consistent across different platforms.

Comment: I've marked the question to be moved.  Parsing the output might belong here, getting it belongs on serverfault. Cheers.

Comment: This can usually be run by a non-root user, too, although often not in the default path.  It's usually found at /usr/sbin/prtdiag

Answer (score 0):

Depends on hardware.

On SUN x86 HW there's usually IPMI controller so then `ipmitool sdr` will print every sensor including FAN speed.

On SUN SPARC HW there's usually system controller accessible on serial port or ever ethernet. Commands varies, start with `help` or `?`, possibly `sensors` will work.